# Create a generality try-block function which catch callback itself with limit times using recursion

Tags: c#, .net

- First, I'm sorry about the title, i don't know how to explain my problem in the title.
  I create a generality function:

```
public T DoSomething<T>(List<object> parameters, ref Exception exception, T _default = default(T), int tryTimes = 3, int waitingSeconds = 5) where T : new()
{
    try {
      // Do something
      // return object T
      return new T(); // this line for void function which does not need return.
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        if (tryTimes > 0) {
            tryTimes -= 1;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitingSeconds * 1000);
            return DoSomething(parameters, ref exception, _default, tryTimes, waitingSeconds);
        }
        else {
            exception = ex;
            return _default;
        }
    }
}
```

and I have many normal functions like that:

```
public bool PingApi(string apiurl, ref Exception exception) {
   try {
     /// call to api
     return true;
   }
   catch(Exception ex) {
     exception = ex;
     return false;
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me to merge them to a greater generality function, please?
Reason for this function: Retry to do something when sure that the reason for catching (in this sample, if internet's connection is corrupted sometimes).
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What did you mean by "merging them to a greater generic function"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The first function looks like it should just run multiple times and abort after a certain number of tries. Wouldn't it be easier to make the attempts via loop and specify the method to execute via [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: To be clear what I mean: [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Qg8xn) I would try it this way - but I still have no idea what you try to achieve.